# How to get Support Action Bar inside a Master/Detail Fragment to set NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, master-detail

Right now I have a typical master/detail pattern, inside detail area I am supposed to display some kind of Tabs structure but with a ViewPager in order to implement the swipe functionality to change between those tabs.

In a Single-Pane-Mode (when using devices) inside detail area, I deploy AreaDetailActivity. Inside of this activity I call the supportActionBar (v7), set the navigation mode, and set the tabs, like this:

```
public class AreaDetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {    

    private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;    

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView( R.layout.view_pager );

        String idTipoAreaActual = getIntent().getStringExtra(  AreaDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID );

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode( ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS );

        //Adapter that returns the selected fragment
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( this, idTipoAreaActual, getSupportFragmentManager() );

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById( R.id.view_pager );
        viewPager.setAdapter( viewPagerAdapter );

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener( new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected( int position ){
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem( position );
            }
        });

        actionBar.addTab( actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(this) );
        actionBar.addTab( actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(this) );
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem( tab.getPosition() );
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1){        
    }
}
```

The above code works perfectly, but I need a way to implement the same functionality in Two-Pane-Mode (actually Tablet Screen). In Two-Pane the detail area deploys a fragment, so I need to call the support action bar and implements the swipe functionality using the ViewPager, but when I do the cast the ActionBar to AreaDetailActivity (thet extends from ActionBarActivity), it shows a Casting error. This is my AreaDetailFragment displayed in Two-Pane-Mode:

```
public class AreaDetailFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Activity activity;
    private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    public AreaDetailFragment( Activity activity ) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu( true );
    }

    @Override 
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.ccmaction_bar, menu);
    }   

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.view_pager, container, false );  
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        String idTipoAreaActual = getArguments().getString( AreaDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID );

        final ActionBar actionBar = ( (AreaDetailActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode( ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS );

        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), idTipoAreaActual, getChildFragmentManager() );

        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById( R.id.view_pager );
        viewPager.setAdapter( viewPagerAdapter );       

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener( new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected( int position ){
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem( position );
            }
        });  
    } 

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem( tab.getPosition() );
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1){        
    }
}
```

Any Ideas??? Thanks for your Time!!!

Comment: Can you show us your XML layout ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nice tutorial for SWIPE/TAP/PAGES: http://indyvision.net/2014/08/android-tutorial-screen-with-tabs-and-swipe-part-i/

Technical information about ACTION BAR: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Un buen tutorial sobre SWIPE/TAP/PAGES: http://indyvision.net/2014/08/android-tutorial-screen-with-tabs-and-swipe-part-i/

Información técnica sobre ACTION BAR: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html